# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Web.Mvc.SelectList>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to add some values into my SelectList data member in my object but I get an error

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {

        var paf = new ProductAddForm();
        paf.Sizes = new SelectList(m.GetProductSizes());
        paf.Suppliers = new SelectList(m.GetAllSuppliersList(), "Id", "Name");

        return View(paf);
    }
```

that is my creat function, and the paf.Sizes / paf.Suppliers code does not work.

My productaddform class:

```
    public class ProductAddForm
{

    public double MSRP { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SelectList> Sizes { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SelectList> Suppliers { get; set; }

    public string UPC { get; set; }


}
```

And my methods in my manager.cs

```
public IEnumerable<SupplierList> GetAllSuppliersList()
    {

        var fetchedObjects = ds.Suppliers.OrderBy(n => n.Name);

        var Suppliers = new List<SupplierList>();

        foreach (var item in fetchedObjects)
        {

            var s = new SupplierList();
            s.Name = item.Name;
            s.Id = item.Id;

            Suppliers.Add(s);
        }

        return (Suppliers);

    }

    public List<string> GetProductSizes()
    {

        return new List<string>() { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };
    }
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: paf.suppliers takes in a `ICollection<SelectList>` Suppliers but you are putting in a single selectlist `new SelectList(m.GetAllSuppliersList(), "Id", "Name");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Suppliers` is a collection of `SelectList`. So you need to Add item into the collection

Change

```
paf.Suppliers = new SelectList(m.GetAllSuppliersList(), "Id", "Name");
```

to

```
paf.Suppliers.Add(new SelectList(m.GetAllSuppliersList(), "Id", "Name"));
```

Comment: @user2981393 Feel free to accept his answer as correct. :)