# Create a separate Method for SelectList to pull in to viewbag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag, selectlist

I use code for a particular select list in a few different places.  It has been annoying that whenever I need to update the data it is pulling - I have to update it in all the different places.  So now I want to create a method that they all reference and update it in one location.  However, the code I have is not working.

Here is the code Where I call the method to put in the viewbag:

```
ViewBag.PrimaryTechnicianId = TechList();
```

And here is the method I am creating:

```
public Action TechList()
{
     Var techList = new SelectList(db.Users.Where(u => u.Status == 1 & u.RoleID == new Guid(Properties.Settings.Default.TechID)).OrderBy(u => u.FullName), "UserId", "FullName");

     return (techList);
}
```

I am receiving an error where I call the method (in the first code) that says (even though I added the reference already)

> The Name 'TicketList' does not exist in the current context

and in the second code on the return (techList) I receive this error:

Cannot explicitly convert type 'System.Web.MVC.SelectList' to 'System.Action'

I have found this where I would change the method in to an IEnumerable but that seems different than my usage.  Am I correct that since I am creating the selectList in the viewbag that it is not an IEnumerable?  [Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Web.Mvc.SelectList>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614215/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-web-mvc-selectlist-to-system-collection)

Comment: You method is returning a `SelectList` so it needs to be `public SelectList TechList() { .. }`. The error you are getting has nothing to do with any code you have shown (nowhere in your code do you have `TicketList`)

Answer (score 1):

Your method should return a `SelectList` instead of an `Action`. In your view you may need to explicitly cast it to a `SelectList` when you pull it out of the `ViewBag`.

```
Html.DropDownList("techList_drpdwn", (SelectList)ViewBag.PrimaryTechnicianId, new { id = "techList_drpdwn" })
```

Comment: This addresses the problem directly. The method returns Action, not SelectList.

Answer (score 0):

Make the return type of your TechList to SelectList instead of Action.
I'm not sure where do you call your ViewBag assignment but try fixing the method return type before calling it as if it has a bug it won't be referenced correctly

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a public class and static method somewhere

```
public class ViewHelpers
{
    public static SelectList TechList(int status, guid role)
    {
        using (var db = new DbContext())
        {
            return new SelectList(db.Users.Where(u => u.Status == status & u.RoleID == role).OrderBy(u => u.FullName).ToList(), "UserId", "FullName");
        }
    }
}
```

then just call this from inside your view

```
@(Html.DropDownList("PrimaryTechnicianId", 
                     ViewHelpers.TechList(1, new Guid(Properties.Settings.Default.TechID))
)
```