# Cannot implicitly convert type 'List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> to 'IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, enums, asp.net-core-mvc, selectlistitem

In my cshtml view I have this pre-made (scaffold) code that I changed a little to be able to put a list of enums down there instead of a textbox:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Color" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Color" asp-items="Model.Colors" class="form-control"></select> 
                <span asp-validation-for="Color" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
```

Error occurs at `Model.Colors`.

And in my model I **tried** doing: `Colors.Add(new List<SelectListItem>());` as told in [Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Web.Mvc.SelectList>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614215/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-web-mvc-selectlist-to-system-collection), but than I would get a different error; *Cannot implicitly convert 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem'*.

Even though `Colors` is a `List<SelectListItem>`.

But before that I had this in the ViewModel:

```
public EnumsDTO.Color Color { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> Colors { get; set; }
public void AddColorViewModel()
{
    Colors = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (Color c in (Color[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Color)))
    {
        Colors.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = ((int)c).ToString(),
            Text = c.ToString()
        });
    }
}
```

I was trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPJ9PPCWxoI

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, this code isnt clear thus its hard to see exactly what the problem is.

Comment: obviously wrong `using` at the top of the file

Comment: @KieranDevlin I was following this tutorial, but to show all code is a little too much because they have nothing to do with this. But it basically goes wrong when the guy in the tutorial tries to get de method to the cshtml-file with `asp-items = Model.etc`

Comment: @Selvin What `using` should I have?

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely `using System.Web.Mvc` namespace in your model at the top of the file. While `SelectListItem` exists there, the one that is expected in the view is from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering` namespace.

Therefore, there are 2 ways to resolve the issue:

## Option 1

1. Get rid of `using System.Web.Mvc;`
2. Add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;`

## Option 2

1. Change the relevant occurrences of `SelectListItem` in your model to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem`

Answer (score 0):

you should first install:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation -Version x.x.x
```

from NuGet according to dependency of your project or class library version and after that change:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

to

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
```

in every usage of `SelectListItem`.